# Action names in post menu cut off in iOS 13

Tags: bug, ios-app

I just updated my iPhone 7 Plus to iOS 13 tonight and noticed that the post menu in the Stack Exchange app became close to unreadable, because the font/text is too large to be properly displayed. Luckily we can still recognize the icons...

[image]

(Yes, app development has been frozen for quite a while but the app continues to serve me well.)

Comment: It’s not almost unreadable, the words are completely covered by elipsis.

Comment: Same here on an iPhone XR.  I do most of my StackExchanging on mobile and (even though I know that the app development is frozen) the App is where I spend the majority of my time answering questions.   This is a bummer.. looks like iOS 13 finally killed the app.

Comment: @Stormblessed I just noticed we edited the question at the exact same time. I didn't overwrite your changes on purpose...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same bug for iPhone 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to iOS 14 fixed this problem for me on iPhone SE:

[image: labels not cut off]

(iOS 14 didn’t cause any major issues with the app either.)

Comment: Same here, no idea how I've missed that (I'm using iOS 14 for 6-8 weeks now ...)