# Feed items cut off in iOS 13

Tags: bug, ios-app

It looks like iOS 13 changed some of the default font sizes, [breaking the post menu in the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333646/295232) but it's also cutting off some of the texts in the feed. Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I find the iOS app in iOS 13 buggier to the point where its unusable most of the time. High time to update it for iOS 13.

Comment: Font size for share and flag buttons no longer respect the system wide setting causing the text to get clipped: https://i.imgur.com/JnOMFX1.jpg