# Some of the Hot Network Questions aren't completely shown in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, hot-questions

Another (minor) bug in the iOS app; unlike my [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333659/feed-items-cut-off-in-ios-13) [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333646/action-names-in-post-menu-cut-off-in-ios-13) bug reports I'm not entirely sure these are related to the launch of iOS 13. The app has the complete list of Hot Network Questions (accessible via the Feed, tap More Hot Network Questions). For some questions, the title isn't fully displayed and they lack the tags and the number of answers as well:

[image]

Comment: I admire the fact you spend time to report bugs of a dead app. :) (i.e. bugs you're well aware will never be fixed, hence it's purely waste of time)

Comment: @ShadowTheCoffeeWizard so Stack Exchange app is officially dead? Not just the stack overflow one and not just the android version

Comment: @user1298069 yes, for years. The programmers who developed the apps are either not working for SE anymore at all, or re-assigned to other teams. There's no longer "mobile app" team inside Stack Exchange the company.

Comment: @ShadowTheCoffeeWizard I don’t understand! I used to get updates regularly and the notes of the updates always explained the improvements till recently when the update stopped. iOS 13 messed up the app and that’s why I m here looking for an answer