# Why do email notifications still advertise the mobile apps?

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, notifications, email

To the best of my knowledge, the Android and iOS mobile apps are moribund. However, an inbox notification email I received this morning (I rarely get them, as I'm online often enough to usually see these things before the email is sent) ends with

> Want instant inbox notifications on your phone? Download the Stack Exchange mobile app for iOS or Android.

This is followed by large icons for the Apple App Store and for Google Play.

Is this just old text that was never edited when the apps were mothballed?

Comment: Because inbox notifications are one of the few features of the mobile apps that still work on most modern phones.

Answer (score 1):

The apps are mothballed, but they're still functional. Even though the user interface is [slowly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333646/295232) [breaking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333659/295232) [apart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333780/295232), it's still working. And even if it wouldn't, push notifications still work as a reminder to visit the site itself with a browser.

I wouldn't mind if that particular sentence would be removed from the email, but I would only consider it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) if the apps weren't listed in the App Store / Play Store anymore (or otherwise completely unusable).

Comment: Not really. push notifications no longer worked for me, and that was the last straw. It stops working when you change device.

Comment: I set up a new Android device a few weeks ago, and it does receive push messages ... It might depend on the device.

Comment: New phone, new Android (for my device): 8 wasn't working great, but enough to check new topics. 9: can't even load the question... Just get the homepage.

Comment: @Glorfindel remember something Kasra said looong ago about registering the device on their side, so if I have more than one active device (which I have, for the kids), it mess that up. In the past I just uninstalled and re-installed until notifications were back, but at some point I decided to stop trying and accepted the fact the app is dead. To be honest, I don't miss those instant notifications. :)