# Cramped UI on iPhone 11 Pro Max

Tags: bug, ios-app

Text is clipped, e.g. *Fa...e* instead of *Favorite*. Also, the text looks like it could be much smaller and still be readable. Another contributing factor is there is a gap of about 0.5 inches (13 mm) at the bottom and 0.8 inches (20 mm) at the top (0.6 inches (15 mm) excluding the notch) that has no content at all. I think the app might need to opt in to full screen or something to put content there. As long as there's nothing critical in the rounded corners or notch section, it should work fine.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPhone12,5)
- OS Version: Version 13.2.3 (Build 17B111)

Comment: The app is discontinued, there won't be a fix for this. The best solution is to just use the mobile site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Action names in post menu cut off in iOS 13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333646/action-names-in-post-menu-cut-off-in-ios-13) - it's an iOS 13 bug, independent of your actual device.

Comment: Why is it being discontinued? Can it be open-sourced for the community to maintain?

Comment: @MooseBoys Open sourcing the front end but not the backend would be challenging for the developers on both sides.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica My assumption is that the app just uses the public API. Does it not?

Comment: @MooseBoys It uses a lot of closed-source mechanics that cannot be reliably open-sourced.